# Using REST API for android apps integration with backend

Tags: android, rest, restful-authentication, backend

I am working on an android app which needs to talk to the backend, securely. I plan to use the REST API. Is there a website which offers a good example code.

Comment: What language are you looking to use?

Comment: Sounds like you have a predicament... you want to "Securely use REST"  ... good luck :)

Comment: Try out Google App Engine if you have time. It scales perfectly well to suit most of your needs.

Comment: Have a look at the Google MBS - https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/